# How to use Application.Exit Event in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, exit

I need to delete some certain files, then user closes program in WPF. So I tried MDSN code from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit.aspx this way:

this code located here `App.xml.cs`

```
public partial class App : Application
{
 void App_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("File deleted");
        var systemPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                                  Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);

                var _directoryName1 = Path.Combine(systemPath, "RadiolocationQ");
                var temp_file = Path.Combine(_directoryName1, "temp.ini");

                if (File.Exists(temp1_file))
                {
                    File.Delete(temp1_file);
                }

    }

}

// App.xaml
<Application x:Class="ModernUIApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
             Exit="App_Exit">
    <Application.Resources>
```

First of all it doesn't delete files, secondly this program stays in the process after I pushed exit button( this is really strange). This code don't give any errors. And finally it doesn't show `MessageBox` So anything wrong here?

I think he just  can`t find this function.

Comment: Have you wired up the `App_Exit` event in the `XAML`?

Comment: @Silvermind anyway nothing happens

Comment: If you put a break point in there, does it get hit? Also show us your logic of the Exit button.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It's quite simple:

Add "Exit" property to the application tag

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication4.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             Exit="Application_Exit">
</Application>
```

and handle it in the "code behind"

```
private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
{
    // Perform tasks at application exit
}
```

The Exit event is fired when the application is shutting down or the Windows session is ending.  It is fired after the SessionEnding event.  You cannot cancel the Exit event.

Comment: Could you look my code one more time, I did exatly like you said, but I get other problems

Comment: I tied it and it's working fine. what is your issue? give me more details. try to remove the property  `ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"` and let me know if it works

Comment: I have removed `ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"` and it started to work properly. Thank you a lot.

Comment: That not how you are supposed to do it. Just `protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)` in the code behind. Register to class own events is avoidable, avoid it.

Answer (score 13):

you should add app_exit in your xaml  code

```
 <Application x:Class="CSharp.App"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" 
  ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
  Exit="App_Exit"
    >
</Application>
```

you  can just hook the event Closing on your main window like this -

```
 <Window Closing="Window_Closing">
```

And in your event do all the work you  need

```
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("File deleted");
    var systemPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                              Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);

            var _directoryName1 = Path.Combine(systemPath, "RadiolocationQ");
            var temp_file = Path.Combine(_directoryName1, "temp.ini");

            if (File.Exists(temp1_file))
            {
                File.Delete(temp1_file);
            }
}
```

Comment: Yes I forget to `add app_exit` event, but here new problem appeared. I updated question

Answer (score 7):

If you don't like adding Exit event to XAML, you could try this alternative.

**Add following method to your `App.xaml.cs`:**

```
protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnExit(e);
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Beware that `base.OnExit(e);` is what invokes the exit event.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to follow MVVM principle you can use  System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Endonext.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding WindowClosingCommand, Mode=OneTime}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel 
{
    ICommand WindowClosingCommand => new RelayCommand(arg => this.WindowClosing());

    private void WindowClosing()
    {
      // do what you want.
    }
}
```

This approach is more testable.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Please note: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556240/wpfmvvm-library-system-windows-interactivity-in-not-available-anymore

Comment: You also need to implement RelayCommand in order for this solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the namespace (MyApp) matches "x:Class=MyApp..."
2. Under properties for `<Application></Application>`, double click on the textbox next to 'Exit'.
3. If you get "Unable to add event handler" then Rebuilding the project fixed it for me.

XAML

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
         Exit="Application_Exit"
>
```

Code behind

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyApp
{ 
   public partial class App : Application
   {
     private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
     {
         //your code
     }
  }
}
```