# Graceful programmatic shutdown of windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows

We have an (C#/.NET) application running on a Windows embedded target that requires the machine to be shut down at the push of a button. Ideally I'd like the program to exit and perform its cleanup (including putting attached hardware into a safe state) before the shutdown takes place. But of course once the program has closed I can't execute the shutdown command! So can this be done?

Comment: Push of which button? On the machine itself or your program's?

Comment: We have an LCD screen with a 4-button keypad on it. There is a menu option for shutting down.

Comment: Updated the answer again, then.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it can be done, and it is very easy.

Start a process that issues "shutdown /s", THEn exit your program.

Comment: That simple? LOL, looks like I overthought it.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `Application.ApplicationExit` event (winforms) which will be called in any case your application is being closed.

[MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit(v=vs.110).aspx).

For WPF:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20347268/558018

---

From C#, the best way to shutdown is:

```
shutdown.exe /f /r /t 0
```

Execute the code through `Process.Start(..)` and your computer will immediately begin its shutdown process.

Of course, before you execute this, you should do your "cleanup" procedures.

Comment: how would that shutdown the __machine__?

Comment: @TaW why should it do that? OP presses "the button".

Comment: That's WinForms only? We're WPF.

Comment: @JulianGold updated the answer. Do mention please such things.

Answer (score 1):

[How to shut down the computer from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shutdown-the-computer-from-c-sharp) took from here :

Works starting with windows XP, not available in win 2000 or lower:

This is the quickest way to do it:

```
Process.Start("shutdown","/s /t 0");
```

Otherwise use P/Invoke or WMI like others have said.

Comment: This shuts the computer down but does not guarantee graceful exit. So I combine this with the Exit event from the WPF and I'm good, I guess?