# Visual Studio Start/Continue Button is Greyed Out after Debug

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This may be the wrong community to ask in (maybe SuperUser?) however I am experiencing a bug with VS. It is very minor but I was curious to see if anyone has seen this before or knows how to fix it.

I have run my project to debug and then upon exiting the application i.e. Application.Current.Shutdown() and Environment.Exit(0) the button at the top, that would usually return to saying start and being enabled, remains disabled and reads "continue".

All of the other methods of debugging the project are still available (Debug Menu / f5), however, it is still a conundrum nonetheless. Please respond if you have seen this before and/or you are aware of a fix.

Please see the image below.

[image: Greyed out Continue Button]

EDIT: Further Information; (any further information that is requested will be added here)

- My application is C# and was started as a WPF Application.

EDIT: Bounty timing out - Just a note, I have updated to latest versions of VS and the basic extensions and I am still experiencing the problem.

Comment: does VS otherwise work? ie pressing F5 restarts debugging?

Comment: Yes, "All of the other methods of debugging the project are still available (Debug Menu / f5)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `Application.Exit();` instead of `Application.Current.Shutdown()`

if still happens, you can try to kill the VS first in the task manager. Then reopen the project.

This one also, you can try to visit this link as my referral.

[How to use Application.Exit Event in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346746/how-to-use-application-exit-event-in-wpf)

Comment: This has solved the problem for me! ... at least it seems to have. I will award the bounty so that my points don't go to waste. I will do further testing and double check though.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Go to Project's Properties > Web Tab > Check Enable Edit and Continue
[image: see image]

With “Enable Edit and Continue” on, the VS debugger starts your web application in IIS Express. When you stop debugging, IIS Express is closed too. With this behavior, you will see the IIS Express system tray shows up during debugging and gone after debugging.

Comment: Hi, my application is not of the "web" type. So this tab does not exist in the properties. I should have stated. This app is a C# WPF-based project.

Comment: Sorry couldn't help :)